# Trivial demonstration. $\nabla J(r,t)=\frac{\hbar}{im}\nabla\psi^{*}\nabla\psi+\frac{\hbar}{im}\psi\nabla^2\psi$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, laplacian, divergence-operator

I can not do the calculation for a very trivial demonstration.
$$J(r,t)=Re \left[ \psi^{*}\frac{\hbar}{im}\nabla\psi \right]$$
I want to demonstrate that 
$$\nabla J(r,t)=\frac{i}{\hbar}[\psi^{*}(H\psi)-(H\psi)^{*}\psi]$$
$$H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\Delta$$
I did the divergence of the definition
$$\nabla J(r,t)=\frac{\hbar}{im}\nabla\psi^{*}\nabla\psi+\frac{\hbar}{im}\psi\nabla^2\psi$$
$$\nabla J(r,t)=\frac{\hbar}{im}\nabla\psi^{*}\nabla\psi-\frac{2}{i}\psi H\psi$$
Now I'm stuck and I do not know how to go on

Comment: You forgot to specify it's the real part you need.

Comment: What does the upside down triangle mean? Is it some type of Delta Function $\Delta$ with a certain property or something?

Comment: @user477343:  From context, it's probably the Laplacian;  some texts write it this way, and some write it as $\nabla^2$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert yes, looking at the mathjax tutorials, I finally found that writing *\nabla* does the trick, $\nabla$ and I learnt what the nabla is... I have yet to learn about the Laplacian though so thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is

$$\nabla J(r,t)=Re\left[\frac{\hbar}{im}\nabla\psi^{*}\nabla\psi-\frac{2}{i\hbar}\psi^* H\psi\right]$$

Notice you forgot taking the real part, you forgot an $\hbar$ factor and you also forgot a complex conjugation sign.

The first term of this expression is purely imaginary so that

$$\nabla J(r,t)=Re\left[-\frac{2}{i\hbar}\psi^* H\psi\right]$$

Another way to express what the real part of a complex number $z$ is, is to compute $(z+z^*)/2$, thus

$$\nabla J(r,t)=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{2}{i\hbar}\psi^* H\psi+\frac{2}{i\hbar}(H\psi)^*\psi\right)=-\frac{1}{i\hbar}\left[\psi^* (H\psi)-(H\psi)^*\psi\right] \; .$$

And since $i=-1/i$, we finished the derivation.